# Problems to reach internet url for wildfly cartridge

Tags: java, binding, port, reverse-proxy, wildfly

I deploy an ear web application on my wildfly 8 app in openshift.

Deploy terminate successfully.

in local mode (127.0.0.1) my webapp respond correctly on http://127.0.0.1:8082/<> with rhc port-forward on.

If it helps, below the output of rhc port forward :

```
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8080 => 127.12.6.2:8080 
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8081 => 127.12.6.3:8080 
java 127.0.0.1:3528 => 127.12.6.1:3528 
java 127.0.0.1:7600 => 127.12.6.1:7600 
java 127.0.0.1:8082 => 127.12.6.1:8080 
java 127.0.0.1:9990 => 127.12.6.1:9990
```

But i dont't reach application with internet urls.
I try http://"full openshift app url":8080/"context-root" or http://"full openshift app url"/"context-root" but not work.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try `http://"full openshift app url"` (port 80 and no context-root)

Comment: If i do this, the server give me a default page of wildfly, not my page context. The problem is that with port-forward on the url 127.0.0.1:8082/"context-root" works, but "full openshift app url/context-root" not work.

Comment: Have you modified the maven task??, also try as I said without port forwarding